# How to implement frozen rows in a QTableView

Tags: qt, row, freeze, qtableview

I'm looking for an example on how to freeze the last row in a QTableView?

Answer (score 2):

There's a thread over on the QtCentre forums here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25484-Functionality-of-QTableView which states that you have to implement this functionality yourself, and gives you some pointers as to how to do it.